@MockBean with Gradle giving indeterministic class for integration test
I am using the following for my integration test
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT,
    classes = [TestSecurityConfig::class],
    properties = ["spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true"],
)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class ImportControllerIT {
    @MockBean
    private lateinit var restClientImpl: RestClientImpl

     @MockBean
     private lateinit var fileManagerImpl: FileManagerImpl

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

 ....
    @BeforeAll
    fun setup() {
        whenever(restClientImpl.getFileContent(uuid, null)).thenReturn(getFileContent("employee.csv"))

        RestAssured.port = port
    }

Wherever I run the code using IntellJ, I see the Mock Bean being used, but when I test the behaviour using gradle command like bash ./gradlew -i integrationTest I see the mock bean and the actual bean being picked randomly.
What am I doing wrong?

Can you annotate your field with @Primary?

I'm not 100% sure but it looks like spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true is causing the randomness of picking the mock bean and the actual bean.
Recommendation: Avoid doing the override of bean definition especially in tests.
Solution: Fix your implementation so that you don't need to override any kind of bean definitions in tests.
